# Laravel Eloquent 3 tables + 1 pivot table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm designing a database to manage `products`. Each product might have multiple `color` and multiple `size` (for example, if the product is a T-shirt, the same shirt can be Small, Medium or Large and be red, green or blue) So I ended up with 3 tables.

- Color: id, name
- Size: id, name
- Product: id, name

I need to be able to store how many products with a specific size and a specific color are in stock and the price for each as well. So I've created a 4th table with the fields:

- color_id, size_id, product_id, quantity, price

I have a model for each table and to define the relationship between all of them I'm using the `belongsToMany` method. The "problem" is that it only allows to specify the foreign key of 2 tables (the example of the documentation is users, roles, and role_user).

Is there a way to define this relationship between these tables in Eloquent?

I need to be able to query the database to get, for example, all the available green, large products. I know how to achieve this using pure SQL, but I'm looking for a more Eloquent version.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include your model relationships?

Comment: just declare two belongsToMany on your product model. where is the issue here ? you can make a unique pivot table with 3 foreign key and use two at a time for a relation, you can also add a belongsToMany from the color to the sizes. The difficulty will be in handling the update/insert procedure.

Answer (score 3):

What you are calling 'products' might be better named 'styles'. The products table is the pivot table with quantity and price. Yes, you have four tables: `colors`, `sizes`, and `styles` (see seeders for examples), plus the color_size_style pivot table, which I'll call `products`:

Migrations for colors, sizes, and styles tables:

```php
// create colors table
Schema::create('colors', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->string('color', 100);
});

// create sizes table
Schema::create('sizes', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->string('size', 100);
});

// create styles table
Schema::create('styles', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->string('style', 100);
});
```

Migration for products table, which is the color_size_style three-way pivot table with additional columns quantity and price:

```php
// create products table
Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->foreignId('color_id')->constrained();
    $table->foreignId('size_id')->constrained();
    $table->foreignId('style_id')->constrained();
    $table->integer('quantity')->default(0);
    $table->decimal('price')->default(0.00);
});
```

Models for color, size, and style

```php
// define color model with size and style relationships
class Color extends Model
{
    public function sizes()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Size::class, 'products');
    }
    public function styles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Style::class, 'products');
    }
}

// define size model with color and style relationships
class Size extends Model
{
    public function colors()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Color::class, 'products');
    }
    public function styles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Style::class, 'products');
    }
}

// define style model with color and size relationships
class Style extends Model
{
    public function colors()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Color::class, 'products');
    }
    public function sizes()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Size::class, 'products');
    }
}
```

Seeders for colors, sizes, and styles:

```php
// seed default colors
class ColorSeeder extends Seeder
{
    public function run()
    {
        $colors = [
            ['color' => 'black'],
            ['color' => 'white'],
            ['color' => 'gray'],
            ['color' => 'maroon'],
            ['color' => 'purple'],
            ['color' => 'navy'],
            ['color' => 'teal']
        ];

        DB::table('colors')->insert($colors);
    }
}

// seed default sizes
class SizeSeeder extends Seeder
{
    public function run()
    {
        $sizes = [
            ['size' => 'XS'],
            ['size' => 'S'],
            ['size' => 'M'],
            ['size' => 'L'],
            ['size' => 'XL'],
            ['size' => 'XXL']
        ];

        DB::table('sizes')->insert($sizes);
    }
}

// seed default styles
class StyleSeeder extends Seeder
{
    public function run()
    {
        $styles = [
            ['style' => 'Unisex Short Sleeve T-Shirt'],
            ['style' => 'Unisex Tank Top'],
            ['style' => 'Unisex Pullover Hoodie'],
            ['style' => 'Women\'s Short Sleeve T-Shirt'],
            ['style' => 'Women\'s Flowy Long Sleeve Shirt'],
            ['style' => 'Men\'s Polo Shirt']
        ];

        DB::table('styles')->insert($styles);
    }
}
```

Now you can add an entry into the products table:

```php
$color = Color::inRandomOrder()->first();
$size = Size::inRandomOrder()->first();
$style = Style::inRandomOrder()->first();

$color->sizes()->attach($size, ['style_id' => $style->id]);

// or in any other combination:
// $color->styles()->attach($style, ['size_id' => $size->id]);
// $size->colors()->attach($color, ['style_id' => $style->id]);
// $size->styles()->attach($style, ['color_id' => $color->id]);
// $style->colors()->attach($color, ['size_id' => $size->id]);
// $style->sizes()->attach($size, ['color_id' => $color->id]);
```

To get all possible combinations (not what we want):

```sql
select colors.color,sizes.size,styles.style from colors join sizes join styles;
```

To get what we've marked as products that exist:

```sql
select products.id,products.quantity,styles.style,sizes.size,colors.color,products.price
from products
join colors on colors.id=products.color_id
join sizes on sizes.id=products.size_id
join styles on styles.id=products.style_id
order by style,size,color;
```

Although technically not necessary, you'll probably want a product model as well. Or maybe a controller is enough - I'm not sure. But this should be enough to get your head around the three-way pivot concept. ;)